# Exception thrown when trying to use ifstream

Tags: exception, visual-c++, ifstream, c++17

I am trying to put lines from a text file into an array of `string`, but I am getting an exception thrown and frankly I am clueless as to what I should do.

Here's the bit of code handling the file:

```
ifstream names("Vehicle_names.txt");
    string vehnames[54];
    if (names.bad())
    {
        return 1;
    }
    while (names)
    {
        names >> vehnames[i++];
    }
    i = 0;
    while (i < 54)
    {
        cout << endl << vehnames[i];
        i++;
    }
```

The exception is thrown next to the following line in iosfwd:

```
static void __CLRCALL_OR_CDECL assign(_Elem& _Left, const _Elem& _Right) _NOEXCEPT
        {   // assign an element
        _Left = _Right;
        }
```

And the error says:

```
Excpetion thrown: write access violation
_Left was 0xCCCCCCCC.
```

I'd really appreciate it if you could help me with this, I'm going mad trying to do something about it.

I'm writing using Visual Studio 2017, if it helps.

Comment: Time to get acquainted with [your debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0k771bt.aspx)

Comment: The 'write access violation' is almost certainly because you are using `i` as an array index into `vehnames` before `i` is ever initialized; so you have no way of predicting what `i`'s value could be.  It could be anything, and C++ does not check at runtime that you are only using indexes within the range of plain arrays.  Instead, you're likely getting an exception from the operating system itself when it detects that you're trying to access memory that you shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

First, it looks as though you are using **i** without declaring **i**. Next, make sure **i** is not pointing at a place where there is nothing to be found. Maybe try something like this...

```
ifstream names("Vehicle_names.txt"); 
int i = 0;
string vehnames[1028]; //ensure there is enough memory allocated to store txt file in string array
if (names.bad())
  return 1;
while (names.good())
      names >> vehnames[i++]; 
int j = 0;
while(j<i)
    cout << vehnames[j++] << endl;
return 0;
```

Although, the solution is unimportant. Try understanding how the code *works.* ...and keep at it!